# Erro ao fazer um request UTL_HTTP. ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: oracle, request

Ao fazer um `request` a determinado `endpoint`, ocorre o erro abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALL_REST_WEBSERV_POST_METHOD
    AS V_WLT_DIRECTORY
    VARCHAR2(4000) := 'file:/oradisk/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/wallet/Cert_occ_17112019.p7b';
    V_WLT_PASSWORD              VARCHAR2(40) := 'testeosc1';
    V_REQUEST    UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    V_RESPONSE   UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    V_TEXT       VARCHAR2(2000);
    CONTENT VARCHAR2(4000) :='{
        "values": [
            {
                "key": "occ-env",
                "value": "https://admin-admin",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "occ-user",
                "value": "meuusuario@tofodido",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "occ-password",
                "value": "xxxxxxx",
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": "occ-key",
                "value": "000000",
                "description": {
                    "content": "",
                    "type": "text/plain"
                },
                "enabled": true
             }
         ],
    }' ;

BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Passou 1'); 

    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET(V_WLT_DIRECTORY
        ,V_WLT_PASSWORD);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Passou 2'); 

    V_REQUEST := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('https://meu_endpointblablabla/'
        ,'POST'
        ,'HTTP/1.1');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Passou 3'); 


    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(V_REQUEST, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(V_REQUEST, 'Authorization', 'OAuth');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(V_REQUEST, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(CONTENT));

    UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(V_REQUEST, CONTENT);

    V_RESPONSE := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(V_REQUEST);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Resposta status : ' || V_RESPONSE.STATUS_CODE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Resposta rasão: '   || V_RESPONSE.REASON_PHRASE);


    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(V_RESPONSE, V_TEXT);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_TEXT);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
                    NULL;
                END;

        EXIT WHEN V_TEXT IS NULL;
    END LOOP;

    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(V_RESPONSE);
END;
```

Alguém já se deparou com esse problema?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho experiências com o wallet manager, mas baseado em alguns casos que encontrei na internet vou tentar te ajudar com o erro **ORA-28759**.

O [Wallet Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm) dá permissões de leitura, escrita e modificação apenas para o usuário que criou o arquivo.

> Wallets are associated with specific user profiles, so no file
>   permissions need to be managed, and the wallets stored in the profile
>   are automatically deleted when the user profile is deleted. You can
>   use Oracle Wallet Manager to create and manage the wallets in the
>   registry.

**Tradução livre:**

> Wallets são associadas a perfis de usuário específicos, portanto,
>   nenhuma permissão de arquivo precisa ser gerenciada e as "carteiras"
>   armazenadas no perfil são excluídas automaticamente quando o perfil do
>   usuário é excluído. Você pode usar o Oracle Wallet Manager para criar
>   e gerenciar as Wallets no registro.

**Possíveis soluções:**

- Modifique as permissões ou copie os arquivos para outro local. Depois
  em [`SET_WALLET`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/utl_ht21.htm) o referencie o novo local do arquivo que no seu
  caso está na `V_WLT_DIRECTORY`.
- Verifique se o caminho da `wallet` é acessível do servidor do banco de
  dados e quais permissões ele possui no diretório.
- Verifique se o auto_login está habilitado. Se a wallet estiver com o [`auto_login`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1006888) habilitado, a senha poderá ser omitida e deverá ser definida como `NULL`.
- Verifique seu arquivo SQLNET.ora ([SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm#CBHGEBEI), [SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF233), [SSL_VERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF235))

**Referência:**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_http.htm#ARPLS71106

Comment: Olá George, bom dia. Demos as permissões para o arquivo e não tivemos sucesso na operação. O problema em alterar o local da wallet é que temos mais dois certificados para Oracle Sales Cloud e Sales Force. Se mudar, os dois sistemas deixam de funcionar porque vai perder o endereço já atribuído.

Comment: @JohnLeenda coloquei mais algumas verificações, Verifique se algo resolverá seu problema.

Comment: Nenhum dos Métodos funcionou infelizmente. :(

Comment: George vim aqui dizer que agora deu certo..  tomamos continuidade no projeto e deu certo a 3 solução

Comment: Boa @GoldenBoy, fico feliz que tenha te ajudado! Quando possível marca como resposta já que resolveu seu problema. E se possível da o voto pra me manter incentivado! kkk ;)

Comment: feito, muito obrigado pela ajuda mesmo